# struts2 jquery load same page on form submission

Tags: jquery, struts2

I am using struts2 (version 2.1.8 )and jquery plugin(version 1.8.3) for building a web 
application.

I am designing a simple use case where on submitting a form , same page gets loaded on a ui, 
in such a way that : 
1)If there is a from validation error , validation message should be displayed on same page.
2)If there is a success message , the message will be displayed on the same page.

The problem I am facing is , in both of the cases , struts2 redirects to results 
specified in the struts.xml but on a separate page and existing page disappears.

Following is my homepage.(I am using tabbed panel to design tabs.)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <sj:head jqueryui="true"/>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <s:url var="addUserUrl" action="inputUser"/>
    <s:url var="deleteUserUrl" action="getDeleteUsers"/>  
    <sj:tabbedpanel id="mytabs2">
      <sj:tab id="tab1" href="%{addUserUrl}" label="Add User"/>
      <sj:tab id="tab2" href="%{deleteUserUrl}" label="Delete User"/>
    </sj:tabbedpanel>
 </body>
</html>
```

Homepage gets loaded with the data returned from "addUserUrl" (inputUser.action), as expected.(addUser.jsp as configured below in struts.xml)

But when addUser.jsp is submitted , success-add.jsp or addUser.jsp are displayed as a separate pages and not within the same page , depending on sucess or validation error as configured in below struts.xml

Is there any way that both of these pages can be displayed within home page itself and not 
as a separate pages.

```
    <action name="inputUser" class="addUserAction" method="input">
        <result name="form">addUser.jsp</result>            
    </action>       

    <action name="addUser" class="addUserAction" method="addUser">
        <result name="success">success-add.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">addUser.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: referring to the link : http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SubmitTag , i am now using sj:submit tag like below in AddUser.jsp file. <sj:submit name="submit" value="AjaxSubmit" href="%{ADDUSER}" targets="tab1"/> where targets = "tab1" is a tab id on page homepage.jsp. But even after trying above code , same page is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think - based on the html code the tab tag generates - the submit tag should be like this:

```
<sj:submit name="submit" value="AjaxSubmit" href="%{ADDUSER}" targets="Add_User"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be javascript errors in your page that's preventing the jquery plugin from binding callbacks to the sj tags. It is most likely caused by some of your scripts conflicting with the jquery script the plugin uses. Check your javascript error log and try commenting out script tags (most probably another jquery script) to find the culprit.